# PugiXML doesn't traverse nested tags

Tags: c++, pugixml

I found pugixml on the internet, and it is quite a nice library, especially for it's format (just a header/source combo, no dll dependencies). My problem is that, I made a format for my engine, but I cannot get all the xml nodes, just the first three, then the whole fun stops. My xml looks like this

```
<Model>
    <Actor childcount="394" meshcount="0" name="sponza.obj">
        <Transform 00="1" 01="0" 02="-0" 03="0" 10="0" 11="1" 12="-0" 13="0" 20="-0" 21="-0" 22="1" 23="-0" 30="0" 31="0" 32="-0" 33="1" />
        <Actor childcount="0" meshcount="1" name="sponza_00">
            <Mesh name="sponza_00-0.mesh" />
            <Transform 00="1" 01="0" 02="-0" 03="0" 10="0" 11="1" 12="-0" 13="0" 20="-0" 21="-0" 22="1" 23="-0" 30="0" 31="0" 32="-0" 33="1" />
        </Actor>
        <Actor childcount="0" meshcount="1" name="sponza_01">
            <Mesh name="sponza_01-0.mesh" />
            <Transform 00="1" 01="0" 02="-0" 03="0" 10="0" 11="1" 12="-0" 13="0" 20="-0" 21="-0" 22="1" 23="-0" 30="0" 31="0" 32="-0" 33="1" />
        </Actor>
        <Actor childcount="0" meshcount="1" name="defaultobject">
            <Mesh name="defaultobject-0.mesh" />
            <Transform 00="1" 01="0" 02="-0" 03="0" 10="0" 11="1" 12="-0" 13="0" 20="-0" 21="-0" 22="1" 23="-0" 30="0" 31="0" 32="-0" 33="1" />
        </Actor>
        <Actor childcount="0" meshcount="1" name="sponza_03">
            <Mesh name="sponza_03-0.mesh" />
            <Transform 00="1" 01="0" 02="-0" 03="0" 10="0" 11="1" 12="-0" 13="0" 20="-0" 21="-0" 22="1" 23="-0" 30="0" 31="0" 32="-0" 33="1" />
        </Actor>
    </Actor>
</Model>
```

I'm using the sample tree walker

```
struct simple_walker : pugi::xml_tree_walker
{
    virtual bool for_each(pugi::xml_node& node)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < depth(); ++i) std::cout << "  "; // indentation

        std::cout << "- name='" << node.name()  << "'\n";


        return true; // continue traversal
    }
};
```

but the application writes just this

```
- name='Model'
  - name='Actor'
    - name='Transform'
```

even when there are clearly more tags in the xml document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the XML is not well-formed.
Attribute names cannot start with a number, i.e. `00="1"` is not valid XML.